# 2 torches with the same power - More lumen?

Tags: visible-light

I didn't find an answer for this.

A friend and me argued about the brightness-impact of multiple bulbs/torches.

I told him, that 2 torches with the same power (the same amount of lumen and everything) hold side by side, won't be a difference in lumen, if you place the measure-device directly in the center of the "beam". So: The brightness is the same.

Means: If I point to the lumen-measure device with one torch (maybe ~0.5m distance), adding another would have no impact on the result, if it has exactly the same power.
He denied and said, that the more torches/bulbs you add, the more brightness you will get.

He said, that if you add another torch, you see 2 rings of light: The center beam contains the power of both, but at the outside (edges), the beams divide and there would be lesser power, where because there is just the beam of one torch.

I draw a picture to show the Idea:

[image]

I said, that you don't have more brightness, but you have a better illumination, which let you think that the light is stronger. But if somebody "beams" to your eyes with one torch, adding another with the same attributes won't make a difference in brightness, if you hold them close together.

If you would put 1000 torches next to each other, it won't be much brighter, but the illumination is of course bigger and this may let you think, that there is stronger light.

Who of us was right? I couldn't get an evidence for my theory, because I lack the required items.

I hope you understand what I mean, my english isn't the best. :)

I hope there are some of you, who can give me a good answer to this. We "fight" about this point since months. :D I couldn't find an evidence on the internet.

Comment: You say there is better illumination. What does this word mean to you?

Comment: @BMS: If you have a dark room with one candle in one edge and you add another one in another edge, you see more, but the brigtness isn't increased, you have just added another source that brings the same amount of light to another edge of the room. But the brightness as all isn't increased. I hope this is the better explanation. :)

Comment: @TrudleR wrong the brightness increases as you add more candles. you just dont realise it increased because it is only one candle added at a time and it's in a faraway corner. if you used a proper detector  and each candle is the same distance away from that detector, then doubling the number of candles doubles the energy reaching the detector as expected

Answer (score 5):

He's right.

If you shine two flashlights on an object, there is twice as much light hitting it as if you used one flashlight.

It's as simple as that.

Comment: This means, that you would make someone blind if you point at him with 20 normal torches? Maybe a dumb question, but the answer doesn't make sense to me (not that this would be your fault, but I cannot believe it). Anyway, thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: @TrudleR: Yes, that is true (it probably wouldn't be blinding, but it would be 20 times brighter). Why does that not make sense to you?

Comment: I have 2 torches. One has 350 lumen and one 250 (ok, at least they're declared like that, they're indeed very bright).

If I darken my room and power on the stronger one, I don't see any difference if I add the weaker one.
The (strength of the) brightness is exactly the same in the center if as if I just turn on the stronger and power off the weaker one.

Comment: @TrudleR: Then your eyes are bad or something, because that makes absolutely no sense. By that reasoning, there is no reason to light up a warehouse using multiple overhead lights, since one lamp ought to illuminate the room as well as 200 lights.

Comment: Ok, thank you. :)
I tried it out with 2 torches (not the same power) and really mentioned a very slight difference.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine each torch gives off marbles instead of light. And instead of a light detector we use a cup. In this model, the number of marbles entering the cup per second is like brightness.

If you have only one torch on, only marbles coming from that torch enter the cup. Now turn on the second torch. There will be more marbles hitting the cup every second. The marbles came from both torches. Likewise, overlapping light beams cause brightness to increase.

Comment: This sounds logical to me, if it really is like that. Does "more light-volume" really also mean "more brightness"?

Answer (score -1):

also, the increase of light is not linear, eg 200 lumens is not twice as bright as 100, the same way 32 degrees is not twice as hot as 16. so it is difficult to notice minor, incremental increases.